# Crud em reactjs

Tags: reactjs, crud

I am studying react js and am creating a simple library design for book control. I'm good at the beginning of my studies and would like to implement a CRUD of books.

I perfectly created the layout and the routes. When I navigate to the book route, I will create a code to list the books. Only from this view / component, I want to create a code that I still do not know how to create the book registration and update view. But I want to call these new screens from the book listing screen. DO NOT WANT TO PLACE EVERYTHING ON A SINGLE VIEW! THAT I CAN DO.

Here's the code I'm doing for you to understand better.

https://github.com/wagnergrilo85/library-react/blob/master/src/screens/book/Book.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file structure can look like this :

- Book.js (here you can handle data, from this component you can manage all smaller component )

```js
import React from 'react';
import BookList from './bookList';

class Book extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(){
            super()
            this.state = {
                books: [],
                book: {},
            }
        }
    
        componentDidMount(){
            // Here you will call API to get full list of book
            // this.setState(books: responseApi)
        }

        showBook(id){
            // Find the single book 
            // this.setState(book: responseApi)
        }

        updateBook(id, data){
            // Find the single book 
            // Get new data
            // Update API
        }

        deleteBook(id){
            // Find the single book
            // Delete book in API
        }
    
        render(){

    
            return(
                <div>
                    <BookList books={this.state.books} />
                </div>
            )
        }
}
```

- BookList.js (show list)
- BookShow.js (show single book info)
- BookUpdate.js
- BookCreate.js

  - BookForm.js

You can start from there and find the rest by yourself

Comment: Hello.

The proposed structure is really great.

Could you post the code of how would it look?

  I've stuck the file and folder structure and found it excellent, but I still have not got a clue how to implement it.

Thank you.

Comment: In your book.js create all function fetch data, create data, update data, delete data etc..

Comment: Is my update solved your problem, can you mark it as solved